# Need to compare cells in Excel

Tags: excel, function, cells

I need to compare two cells and then get a count for everything. It would be best just to show you.

```
      1                2
    A Schools          Details
    B Example school   L
    C Example school   M
    D Example school   L
    E Second school    L
```

So that is a very basic form of my table. There are around 56 schools and about 12 detail letters. The goal here is to get a count of all the "L" details that belong to "example school" all the "M" details that belong to "example school" and the same for the "second school"

I would like to end up with something like

```
    Example school: 200 L details
    Example school: 50 M details
    Second school: 90 R details
```

Hopefully I made my point clear enough here! Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not use a PivotTable for this?  It would be much easier than the formula involved.

Comment: Thats the problem is we are not incredibly familiar with how a pivot table would solve this. We figured it would work but again we have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is how you would do this in a basic PivotTable:

I've created an sample data set like in your example

[image]

Now, go to your *Insert* menu and click *PivotTable*

[image]

Select the cell range for the PivotTable and click OK

[image]

You now have a PivotTable in a new tab:

[image]

Check *Schools* and *Details* to add them to your PivotTable

[image]

[image]

Now move *Details* from the Row Labels block to the Column Labels block, and drag another instance of *Details* to the Values block.  The default value is count.

[image]

It is really worth it to learn how to effectively use PivotTables.  I use these regularly to very quickly compare hundreds of thousands of rows and over a hundred columns of data, and it's so easy to manipulate the results to meet your needs, or create a PivotChart from the data.  Our executive team loves how the charts and tables look when I put together a report for them.

Comment: +1 Countifs are one thing, but pivot tables are much more powerful and versatile

Answer (score 2):

If you have excel 2007 or newer, you could use `=countifs("A:A","Example School","B:B","L")` for each one of those. That formula would give you the number of L's that Example School had.

Then you just change the L to M or any other one for all the details for Example School.
Rinse and repeat for second school.

Comment: @M.Stair If that worked for you, please mark it as the answer...also...glad I could help :)

Comment: It did help but Howards solution was much more effective. thank you both!